# Images in the thumbnail are not appearing when pasting a URL on Facebook in a React.js application

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm attempting to showcase thumbnail images, titles, and descriptions when sharing a URL on Facebook or other social media platforms, but it's not displaying as expected. Could you please assist me with this issue? I also attempted to use the Facebook debugger, but the issue remained unresolved.

https://www.weblession.com/initial-scale-in-html

Comment: Your content comes from a JavaScript file (e.g. main.90b07d8b.js), but most applications that use Open Graph meta data (like Facebook) don't support JavaScript. Most apps download the first 10K of your HTML file and then look for the og tags.

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62559163/1011984) may help you.